# Ordering queryset by model string

Tags: django

I'm defining the string for a model as follows:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    company_name = ...
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...

    def __str__(self):

        if self.company_name != None and self.company_name != "":
            return self.company_name
        else:
            return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

When querying for customers, is it possible to order the query by the string that represents the model instance?

eg
c = Customers.objects.all().order_by('???????')

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should define a property (using `@property` decorator) and use related field for your sorting purpose? But I really do not understand your `__str__` defined as company name, far from being unique! To be honest, it does not make sens to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotations to generate the same string as your `__str__` method in a queryset, you can then order by that annotation.

[`Concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) can be used to join first_name and last_name into a single field

[`Coalesce`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) will return the first non-null value, this can be used to implement your if/else

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Concat

Customer.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).annotate(
    display_str=Coalesce('company_name', 'full_name')
).order_by('display_str')
```